# “Visual Studio is Busy” / Hang and seemingly random errors in VS 2022

Tags: docker, visual-studio

I have been using Visual Studio for 30+ years (since it came on a dozen floppies. Likely wasn't called VS until Win 3.1). Over the past month or two, I’ve had more crash/hang/Visual Studio is Busy, than all years combined (maybe a slight exaggeration). It’s junk. I have no idea where to go.

Our project has been going on for five years. It is made of several Solutions. Four are workers running in Docker (Linux) on top of Windows 10. All components are updated (.Net 6).   There is a Winforms Solution and a Xamarin Solutions. We thought the Workers were all set and have spent the past few months on the Xamarin and Winforms Solutions (it’s a self-funded startup. No resources for proper regression testing at every release of VS).

We did the usual delete bin and obj directories, rebuild etc. I wish I could narrow it down, but I can’t find a pattern. Except it usually gives the “VS is busy, reporting to Microsoft” when loading a solution. Sometimes there is an error in a generated Docker file (Value cannot be null). Or, “the required Operating system is not available”. After rebooting, it is magically available.

In the past, we’ve debugged with eight copies of VS running and had no issues. The build machine had 96 gigs memory, i9.

Is there any way to roll back to a 32-bit version or another older version of Visual Studio? I haven’t considered JetBrains Rider before but am looking at it now (I know it doesn’t support Winforms).

I understand I am not providing detail enough for a solution but maybe if you had similar issues in the past, any guess would be helpful.

Thanks!

More Info:

I run a Worker, it loads fine.  I run another worker (in a different copy of VS) and I get the following error. This is from a generated Docker file. No changes.   I then close VS; reopen and run. It works fine.

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   MSB4064 The "OutDir" parameter is not supported by the "ContainerBuildAndLaunch" task loaded from assembly: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Containers.Tools.Tasks, Version=17.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a from the path: C:\Users\orgth.nuget\packages\microsoft.visualstudio.azure.containers.tools.targets\1.15.1\tools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Containers.Tools.Tasks.dll. Verify that the parameter exists on the task, the  points to the correct assembly, and it is a settable public instance property.  PWorker C:\Users\orgth.nuget\packages\microsoft.visualstudio.azure.containers.tools.targets\1.16.1\build\Container.targets 230

Comment: What version are you running? (Current version is `17.2.5`)

Comment: This is not a VS issue but a Net issue.  Always compile in latest Net and then target version that is being used.  Make sure the correct runtime version is installed on target.  There have been a lot of changes in Net to make compatible with Linux machines.  The entire low level interface was updated to make functions compatible with Linux and windows.  It has been a slow process starting with Core 3.1.

Comment: I am running the latest verson of .Net 6 and VS. We never had an issue with .Net 5  Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Current
Version 17.2.5

Answer (score 3):

Funny thing, when you first start coding, if something is not working, you assume it is caused by something other than yourself. After many years of coding, you figure that every time there is an unexplainable issue, it is probably your fault. After trying everything I could imagine, I ran “repair,” and all issues magically disappeared.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I was running into similar issue, the simple "repair" did the trick. Thanks for reminding us of the KISS principle..

Comment: One nice thing that MS could do is saving after/before from file/folders/settings when doing repairs then we understand what was "fixed"

Comment: I don't understand, what "repair" you ran. On what? Where is this repair feature to be found?

Comment: Happened to me, ran "dotnet restore" and everything went back to normal

Answer (score 0):

Just adding my experience of this in case it's of relevance/help.

I've found AdGuard was causing the problem - uninstalling fixed it straight away.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34787363)

Comment: Well, it fixed my problem which was identical to that in the question posted. How does my response "not really answer the question"?

Comment: The default comments that come out of the review queue are sometimes a little weird. What was meant here, is that you could make the answer a little more extensive if you like, add the steps with commands for example, so it's a little less subjective and more generic.

Answer (score 0):

I just started messing with SignalR and VS2022 is giving me "Visual Studio is busy." I agree with general quality issues with Visual Studio these days. Maybe they should do a technology freeze for couple years and just focus on getting things work like supposed to.